# json_decode adds [0] nodes for each dimension

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to prepare an array from json so I can import the data into my database and json_decode adds additional "nodes" for every dimension.

```
array(1) {
  ["STOCK_DATA"]=>
  array(625) {
    [0]=>  <-- THIS HERE
    array(5) {
      ["MATNR"]=>
      string(18) "000000000000300352"
      ["MATNR_OUT"]=>
      string(6) "300352"
      ["LABST"]=>
      float(100)
      ["MEINS"]=>
      string(2) "ST"
      ["ZAL_VKORG"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>  <-- THIS HERE
        array(8) {
          ["VKORG"]=>
          string(4) "2044"
          ["MATNR"]=>
          string(18) "000000000000300352"
          ["MATNR_OUT"]=>
          string(6) "300352"
          ["MEINS"]=>
          string(2) "ST"
          ["LABST"]=>
          float(100)
          ["VRKME"]=>
          string(2) "ST"
          ["LABST_VRKME"]=>
          float(100)
          ["ZAL_WERKS"]=>
          array(1) {
            [0]=>  <-- THIS HERE
            array(8) {
              ["WERKS"]=>
              string(4) "2044"
              ["MATNR"]=>
```

Does anyone know why this happens?

I'm using `json_decode($stockJson, true);`

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation:

> When TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.

An associative array has explicite indexes. That is why json_decode adds the zeros.

Comment: The thing is that another json I processed didn't produce additional nodes. So If I understand correctly the new json file has objects for every "node"?

Comment: json_decode returns an object or an associative array. Here you got an associative array, because you set the parameter for an array to true.

What was your input for the array without additional nodes?